# Call a method at a certain time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am developing an application that has a small feature of sending some SMS messages and Emails using some external web services.

These messages can be scheduled to be sent right now or in the future on a certain date at a certain time. They can also be scheduled to be sent every day/week/month.

How can I design my system to "know" when to call the sending method (without polling)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Quartz.net for task schedule.
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

You can use this with windows service.

Answer (score 2):

Or you have to use a kind of "External Scheduler" - which means - to use external polling, or to implement scheduler by yourself. I think that there's no any decisions without any polling at all...

Comment: Found it!
There's an open source that is called Quartz(.net) ..
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/
And of course great tutorial:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Enjoy!

Comment: I know that project 8-) Very useful but may be a little bit overcomplicated for tiny projects or for very simple tasks. In such cases may be more useful to use simple polling with the list of "wakeup events"