# How to run a function in every 10 minutes with in the loop using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have a loop that continuously run a function based on some condition.
Now, I want to call that function every 10 minutes only within the loop.
I am using Visual Studio 2005. My code is:

```
    while (boolValue == false)
    {
         Application.DoEvents();
         StartAction();    //i want to call this function for every 10 minutes only
    }
```

I am using the System.Timers, but it's not calling the function. I don't know what's wrong.

My code is:

```
   public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
   while (boolValue == false)
   {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
   }

   private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
        Application.DoEvents();
        StartAction();
   }
```

Comment: Try Quartz.net job scheduler.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633662/call-a-method-at-a-certain-time
It's an opensource

Comment: `aTimer.AutoReset = false;` there is your problem

Comment: If you want to do this indefinitely (even after the app is closed), consider writing an app to do it once - even a console app. Then add a Scheduled Task in Windows to run every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Have it trigger every ten minutes.

The [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0wdddfy.aspx) in the more specific version is a pretty good example actually

**UPDATE**

In your updated code, I would change it to this:

```
public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
...
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.AutoReset = false; //This should be true if you want it actually looping
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

I do not see a reason to have a while loop. My guess is that the while loop is not being triggered at all. Also, you should probably set the AutoReset to true so this does run continuously.